# IIS 7 - Authentication in IIS vs Authentication in web.config

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, windows-authentication

I'm relatively new to using IIS 7. I'm getting confused by the various options that IIS 7 provides.

What does setting authentication mode="Windows" do in the web.config of my ASP.net site do?
What does enabling Windows authentication in the Authentication module in IIS 7 do?

What is the difference between these two? Does one override the other? Does this change whether you run in integrated vs classic mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS7 leverages web.config files.  There is tight integration in IIS7 and ASP.NET any changes made in the web.config are reflected in the management console and changes in the management console write changes into the web.config.

As far as windows authentication it uses the servers  local Windows users as its user store.  This is typically more useful for an intranet application that has tight security requirements and existing active directory user base.

Most internet facing applications should use Forms authentication or a custom authentication provider.  You user store can be in the web.config but most applications would keep their userstore in a database

Comment: I really can't understand, in which part of your post the answer occurs for the question where is the difference between the two configurations!!